# Why does a different image source with CSS transition not work when hovered?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` tag that I want to change the image source to another image source when I hover over it, while having the transition effect on the image as well. The transition works with a `background-image` property for a `<div>` tag, but not with the `content` property for an `<img>` tag.
So far this is what I have:

```
.topLogo {
    height: 64px;
    content: url(image1.png);
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.topLogo:hover {
    height: 64px;
    content: url(image2.png);
}
```

Comment: The `content` property can only be used with pseudo elements, like `:before` and `:after`. However, pseudo elements can't be placed on image elements. You have to work out a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `content:` is for the content between tags.  It wouldn't work for `<img>` beause there's no closing `</img>`.

There's no way to alter HTML attributes with CSS.  You could use javascript/jquery.  I have a feeling you don't want to though.

Since you're already using CSS to set the URL, why not use a blank `<span>` or `<div>` instead of an `<img>`?

```
<span class="topLogo"></span>

<style>
    .topLogo:before {
        height: 64px;
        content: url('image1.png');
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    .topLogo:before:hover {
        height: 64px;
        content: url('image2.png');
    }
</style>
```

Comment: The `content` property doesn't refer to existing content. It is used to generate content for the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements. But since the `<img>` tag cannot contain other elements, it also doesn't have `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: I was able to get around not using the :before and :after pseudo elements, but it does work with a `<div>` tag and make that a link, while using the `background-image:` as the source image.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
content: url('image1.png');
```

Try this

```
background-image: url('image.png');
```

Here is a good site to learn more
http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/hover.html

Comment: I didn't specify this before, I want the photo to act as an `<a>` and make it transition when hovered that way.

Comment: So add an <a href="#"> <span class="topLogo"></span></a> around the span